# DatePipe is not working correctly in Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, date, pipe, google-cloud-firestore

In my Angular application after upgrading from version 5 to 6, this error is occurring when using DatePipe.

I'm saving a Date () object that the [mat-date-picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) creates in the Cloud Firestore with the name of the date_field, when returned try to show on screen to the user but does not appear.

I checked the database and it is saving correctly, but I can not display it on the screen for the user in the child_name field.

When you try to display the date_field column in [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and use DatePipe to format the date error is occurring.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="data_nascimento">
   <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>Data de nascimento</mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let paciente" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>
      <p class="text-truncate">{{paciente.data_nascimento | date}}</p>
   </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

After upgrading to Angular 6 the following error occurs:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1531364400, nanoseconds=0)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4238)
    at DatePipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.DatePipe.transform (common.js:5151)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:10801)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11375)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11333)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11970)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:11956)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PacientesComponent.html:81)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11948)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11320)
View_PacientesComponent_10 @ PacientesComponent.html:81
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:12174
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1650
(anonymous) @ core.js:5102
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4030
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5102
(anonymous) @ core.js:4938
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4071
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3927
next @ core.js:4938
schedulerFn @ core.js:3721
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3713
checkStable @ core.js:4040
onHasTask @ core.js:4084
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.AsyncObserver.scheduleEvent @ index.cjs.js:15061
push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.AsyncObserver.next @ index.cjs.js:15050
push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.QueryListener.raiseInitialEvent @ index.cjs.js:7610
push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.QueryListener.onViewSnapshot @ index.cjs.js:7550
push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.EventManager.onChange @ index.cjs.js:7487
(anonymous) @ index.cjs.js:8572
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
PacientesComponent.html:81 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 4, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you got a field with format Date from firebase you have to convert it with  toDate() before your pipe for example:

```
{{paciente.data_nascimento.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: But my DatePicker field did not display the date because a Timestamp is returned, I need to return a Date ()

Comment: this function toDate() convert Timestamp format to valid Date, for example
Timestamp(seconds=1531605600, nanoseconds=0) will be changed to
Sun Jul 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Comment: I had the same problem and toDate() function did the trick for me with an Angular 6 app using firestore backend!

Comment: can someone help answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414341/angular-date-pipe-not-working-how-to-fix  ?

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the wrong type of argument. The Date filter accepts Date objects, numbers (number of milliseconds since epoch) and string (see [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)).

I'm not sure what the Timestamp type is, but it looks like it has a seconds property.

Try to get the number of milliseconds since epoch from that object

```
{{(paciente.data_nascimento.seconds * 1000) | date}}
```

Or there might be a built in method to get it

**Edit** Apparently, since you are using Firebase, you can call the built-in `toDate` method to convert the Firebase object to a plain JS `Date` object

```
{{paciente.data_nascimento.toDate() | date}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use **`toDate()`** to convert a Firebase Timestamp to a Javascript Date object before your pipe:

`{{ paciente.data_nascimento.toDate() | date }}`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when i was calling Firebase API and displaying data on my app. I fixed it simply by converting Firebase datetime into JavasScript using toDate() function like below -

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.date.toDate() | date}}</mat-cell>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 on wards you have to use a function `toDate()`. As well as there are so many date pipes available in the [Angular](https://angular.io/) official website. You can check the available pipes and documents on this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). for an example I use fullDate pipe. See my code below
`<h3>Posted By {{blog.author}} &bull; {{blog.published.toDate() | date:'fullDate'}}</h3>`.

I hope you will get the answer